# How to create a collection with several model types in backbone.js?

Tags: inheritance, backbone.js, javascript-framework

I'm trying to get this to work but I struggle with it. My Collection ends up empty when I check the `success` callback on `fetch`. It doesn't give me any clear errors thou during `parse`. Here's my code:

My collection:

```
VOR.Collections.GridItems = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : VOR.Models.GridItem,
        url: "assets/data/grid.json",
        parse: function(response){
            var self = this;

            _.each(response, function(griditem){
                switch(griditem.type){
                    case "news":
                        self.add(new VOR.Models.NewsGridItem(griditem));
                        break;
                    default:
                        self.add(new VOR.Models.StandardGridItem(griditem));
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
});
```

This is how I create the collection:

```
griditems = new VOR.Collections.GridItems();

griditems.fetch({
    error: function(e) {console.log(e);},
    success: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg)
    });
```

When I console log `msg` I get: 
    Object { length=0, models=[0], _byId={...}, more...}

I've also logged the `parse` function in the collection and it runs thru the JSON file just fine...any ideas on what could be wrong here? The length of the `msg` object should be 5..i.e. that's how many times the `parse` function loops and (should) add a model to the collection.

Answer (score 19):

A nice way of handling this is to redefined the `model` attribute, which tell the collection how to add a new model to the collection, as explained in this POST : [A Backbone.js Collection of multiple Model subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933524/a-backbone-js-collection-of-multiple-model-subclasses/6934682#6934682) (thanks @rulfzid, who answered my question :))

In your case, you should be able to define the model attributes like this :

```
var VOR.Collections.GridItems = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  url: "assets/data/grid.json",

  model: function(attrs, options) {
    switch(attrs.type) {
      case "news":
        return new VOR.Models.NewsGridItem(attrs, options);
      default:
        return new VOR.Models.StandardGridItem(attrs, options);
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This is much better than doing it in `parse` because this for bootstrapped data as well.

Comment: I think that first line should be `var VOR.Collections.GridItems = Backbone.Collection.extend({`

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to store your grid items in different collections and wrap them with model like this:

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'assets/data/grid.json'
    newsItems: Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: VOR.Models.NewsGridItem
    }),
    standartItems: Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: VOR.Models.StandardGridItem
    }),

    initialize: function() {
        this.newsItems = new this.newsItems();
        this.standartItems = new this.standartItems();

        this.newsItems.bind('all', function() {
            this.trigger.apply(this, arguments);
        }, this)
        this.standartItems.bind('all', function() {
            this.trigger.apply(this, arguments);
        }, this)
    },

    parse: function(request) {
        _.each(response, _.bind(function(griditem) {
            switch (griditem.type) {
                case "news":
                    this.newsItems.add(griditem);
                    break;
                default:
                    this.standartItems.add(griditem);
                    break;
            }
        }, this));
    }
})

model.fetch()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// **parse** converts a response into a list of models to be added to the
// collection. The default implementation is just to pass it through.
parse : function(resp) {
  return resp;
},
```

This is what the doc says you should do in parse. Whatever you return will be set as the collection starting array. This is where it is called from:

```
  options.success = function(resp) {
    collection[options.add ? 'add' : 'refresh'](collection.parse(resp), options);
    if (success) success(collection, resp);
  }
```

So I would suggest to change your parse to:

```
return _.map(response, function(griditem){
    switch(griditem.type){
        case "news":
            return new VOR.Models.NewsGridItem(griditem);
            break;
        default:
            return new VOR.Models.StandardGridItem(griditem);
            break;
    }
});
```