# Backbone Collection with multiple models?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I'm learning Backbone.

I want to create a list that can contain different  models, with different attributes.

For example, listing folder contents, which could include models of type file and models of type folder, in any order.

```
file : {
  title : "",
  date : "",
  type : "",
  yaddayadda : ""
}

folder : {
  title : "",
  date : "",
  haminahamina : ""
}
```

What is the proper way to represent this in Backbone?  Is it possible to have a single Collection with multiple models?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933524/a-backbone-js-collection-of-multiple-model-subclasses/6934682#6934682

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Create a base model that your other models inherit from:

```
var DataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // Whatever you want in here
});

var FileModel = DataModel.extend({
    // Whatever you want in here
});

var FolderModel = DataModel.extend({
    // Whatever you want in here
});
```

And make the `model` type of the collection be that same base model:

```
var DataCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: DataModel
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  When DataCollection is passed to a view to be rendered, how would you render an attribute that belongs to FileModel or FolderModel?

Comment: You can always check if `obj instanceof FileModel` (or `FolderModel`) and render appropriately.

Comment: That's how I would do this as well but how are you passing in the DataCollection that you're speaking of (AJAX call)? If that's the case, you will have to check if that unique property exists on the response (ie, if (someModel.someUniqueProperty) { // render it with a view that will handle that property value};).

Answer (score 17):

You could also do it the backbone way. Check out the docs [backbone collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection)

Basically you would create different models adding a tie breaker attribute say "type" in this case.

```
var file = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            // will need to include a tie breaker attribute in both models
            type: 'file'
        }
    }),
    folder = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            // tie breaker
            type: 'folder'
        }
    });

var fs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: function(model, options) {
        switch(model.type) {
            case 'file':
                return new file(model, options);
            case 'folder':
                return new folder(model, options);
        }
    }
});

// after that just add models to the collection as always
new fs([
    {type: 'file',name: 'file.txt'},
    {type: 'folder',name: 'Documents'}
]);
```

Comment: i like this method, not only is it "the backbone way" but it doesn't require the extra business logic @dennis mentioned above, in fact you'll never need any workarounds at all because it will all work like you would expect it to. also, i believe you meant the line to read: `var fs = Backbone.Collection.extend({`

Comment: Please note that this breaks `this.model.prototype.idAttribute`, so you should take a look at Maciej's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35603643/1218980) which solves this with `ModelFactory.prototype.idAttribute`.

Comment: Or just override the collection `modelId` function to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone [documention](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) is not complete in this case. It will not work when used with `merge:true` option and `idAttribute`. In that case you need to:

```
var ModelFactory = function (attr, options) {
  switch (attr.type) {
    case 'file':
      return new file(attr, options);
    case 'folder':
      return new folder(attr, options);
  }
};
ModelFactory.prototype.idAttribute = '_id';

var fs = Backbone.Model.extend({
   model: ModelFactory
});
```

Comment: `ModelFactory.prototype.idAttribute` is really important here as it avoids duplicates.

Comment: Overriding the collection `modelId` function would be equivalent.