# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined with Backbone collection using different models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

With Backbone (1.2.3), I'm trying to build a collection using multiple models using the collection's [`model` property](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model):

```
var coll = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: function(attrs, options) {
        switch(attrs.type) {
            case 'type-a':
                return new BackboneModelA(attrs, options);
            case 'type-b':
                return new BackboneModelB(attrs, options);
        }
    },
    modelId: function(attrs) {
        return attrs.type + ':' + attrs.id;
    }
});

new coll([
    {type: 'type-a', id: 1}
]);
```

But it throws an error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined(…)
```

Actually, `modelId()` is called twice and the second time, `attrs` is `undefined`.

PS: I know it's quite a duplicate of this : [Backbone Collection with multiple models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263765/backbone-collection-with-multiple-models) but I haven't found anything helpful there.

Comment: Can you upgrade Backbone to the latest? I think the arguments to the `model` function are new-ish so they might not be supported in 1.2.3.

Comment: That code works just fine with Backbone 1.2.3 - https://jsfiddle.net/adeo857x/

Answer (score 0):

*[`modelId`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/05fde9e201f7e2137796663081105cd6dad12a98/backbone.js#L1068) is supported in 1.2.3.*

The first time `modelId` is called, it's in the collection `get` function at line [969](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/05fde9e201f7e2137796663081105cd6dad12a98/backbone.js#L969):

```
var id = this.modelId(this._isModel(obj) ? obj.attributes : obj);
```

At that point, `obj` is `{type: 'type-a', id: 1}` and it is sent to `modelId` as-is.

The second time that `modelId` is called, it's in the collection `_addReference` function, at line [1126](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/05fde9e201f7e2137796663081105cd6dad12a98/backbone.js#L1126):

```
var id = this.modelId(model.attributes);
```

It means that at that point, `model` is **not a Backbone model and that `model.attributes` is undefined**.

Without the code of `BackboneModelA`, we won't be able to help you further, but you should look into it and make sure it extends `Backbone.Model`.

Comment: Actually, `BackboneModelA` extends `Backbone.RelationalModel`. Do you think that's the reason it doesnt work ?

Comment: @Menencia Out of the box, `Backbone.RelationalModel` works in this case. You should put a breakpoint in your `modelId` function and explore the stack trace checking if the `model.attributes` hash exist.