# Feed backbone collection with multiple different model classes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have several models which have their own url/api they can fetch.

I would like to keep them in a collection.

- does it sound like a good idea?
- how would you fetch them? (I'm thinking just to get the model I want to update from the collection then fetch it)

Let me know what you think, if you have any theoretical reading/advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backbone Collection with multiple models?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263765/backbone-collection-with-multiple-models)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A collection can contain any raw objects or any models derived from a `Backbone.Model`. Fetching a collection makes sense only if you have an API endpoint which returns an array of objects.

If you want to fetch a specific model, you can keep a reference to it, or just [`get`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-get) it inside your collection, and then call `fetch` on it.

It can cause problems when you have `id` collisions, where identical ids are considered the same model and are merged together.

```
var book = new Book({ id: 1, title: "My Book" }),
    note = new Note({ id: 1, title: "note test" });

var collection = new Backbone.Collection([book, note]);
console.log(collection.length); // 1
```

Ways to avoid `id` collisions:

- don't use ids for these models if possible, Backbone will use their [`cid`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-cid).
- use [GUIDs](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier).
- make a custom `id` attribute composed of identifying data, like prepending the `type` attribute. (`book1`, `note1`).

A way to make a multi model collection is to use the [`model` property](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model) as a function. Though it doesn't prevent `id` collision by default.

```
var BooksAndNotes = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    /**
     * Different models based on the 'type' attribute.
     * @param {Object} attrs   currently added model data
     * @param {Object} options
     * @param {Backbone.Model} subclass dependant of the 'type' attribute.
     */
    model: function ModelFactory(attrs, options) {
        switch (attrs.type) {
            case "book":
                return new Book(attrs, options);
            case "note":
                return new MTextSession(attrs, options);
            default:
                return new Backbone.Model(attrs, options);
        }
    },
    // fixes this.model.prototype.idAttribute and avoids duplicates
    modelId: function(attrs) {
        return attrs.id;
    },
});

var collection = new BooksAndNotes([{
    title: "My Book",
    type: 'book'
}, {
    title: "note test",
    type: 'note'
}]);
```

See similar questions about multiple models in a collection:

- [A Backbone.js Collection of multiple Model subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14263765/1218980)
- [Backbone Collection with multiple models?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14263765/1218980)